# Como unir 2 elementos de diferentes tablas y que coincidan?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este diagrama de relaciones, quiero mostrar los nombres de los profesores y el nombre de las asignaturas que impartieron. He visto que con alguna consulta Join se puede hacer pero he intentado varias y me arroja error o me muestra solo los nombres de los profesores:

```
 Select NombreProf, NombreAsig
 from profesor
 inner join asignatura on profesor.RutProf
 in imparte = asignatura.idAsignatura in imparte.
```

Como tendría que ser la consulta sql en este caso?

Comment: añade la consulta que haz intentado aunque tengas errores

Comment: select NombreProf, NombreAsig from profesor inner join asignatura on profesor.RutProf in imparte = asignatura.idAsignatura in imparte;

Comment: dale editar a tu pregunta y añade esto ahi

Answer (score 1):

Te falta hacer el Join con la tabla pivote, ya que lo estás haciendo directamente con la asignatura, y directamente, no tienen relación.

```
SELECT
  NombreProf, NombreAsig 
FROM Profesor
INNER JOIN Imparte ON  Imparte.Profesor_RutProf = Profesor.RutProf
INNER JOIN asignatura ON Imparte.Asignatura_idAsignatura = Asignatura.idAsignatura;
```

Comment: Al ver la consulta en la pregunta de @Christian, veo que esta algo perdido con el tema de los joins, no estaria mal que ademas de darle la respuesta, darle una breve explicación de lo que son los joins y sobre todo como funciona el ejemplo que le compartiste. Saludos.

Comment: A partir de el primer ON me pierdo, no entiendo la semántica a partir de esa parte

Answer (score 0):

La sentencia JOIN (unir, combinar) de SQL permite combinar registros de una o más tablas en una base de datos relacional.
Con esta operación cada registro en la tabla A (Imparte) es combinado con los correspondientes de la tabla B (Profesor y Asignatura) 
que satisfagan las condiciones que se especifiquen en el predicado del JOIN. La palabra reservada ON permite 
la ejecucion de la comparacion de las claves de la tabla A y la tabla B.

Teniendo en cuenta esto entonces:

`select 
    Profesor.NombreProf,
    Asignatura.NombreAsig 
from 
    Imparte 
join
    Profesor on  Profesor.RutProf = Imparte.Profesor_RutProf
join
    Asignatura on Asignatura.idAsignatura = Imparte.Asignatura_idAsignatura;`